# Use integration test to verify Liquibase database changesets in JEE6 with Arquillian

Tags: integration-testing, java-ee-6, liquibase, jboss-arquillian

we are using Liquibase for db migrations and Arquillian for integration tests.

We would like to have an automated way to see if our xml changesets are correct, that means if they match with the hibernate entities. Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Why don't you use liquibase and hibernate as they're designed to work together? See: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/hibernate.html

Comment: The liquibase-hibernate documentation has moved to https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki